# How do I parse a captured packet in python?

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, raw-sockets

I have a capture packet raw packet using python's sockets:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))

while True:
    message = s.recv(4096)
    test = []
    print(len(message))
    print(repr(message))
```

I assumed that the packet returned would be in hex string format, however the printout of `print(repr(message))` get me something like this:

```
b'\x00\x1b\xac\x00Gd\x00\x14\xd1+\x1f\x19\x05\n\x124VxC!UUUU\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\xcc=\xcd\xccL>\x9a\x99\x99>\xcd\xcc\xcc>\x00\x00\x00?\x9a\x......'
```

which has weird non hex characters like `!UUUU` or `=`.  What encoding is this, and how do I decode the packet?

---

I know what the packet looks like ahead of time for now, since I'm the one generating the packets using [winpcapy](http://code.google.com/p/winpcapy/):

```
from ctypes import *
from winpcapy import *
import zlib
import binascii
import time


from ChanPackets import base, FrMessage, FrTodSync, FrChanConfig, FlChan, RlChan


while (1):

    now = time.time()

    errbuf = create_string_buffer(PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE)
    fp = pcap_t
    deviceName = b'\\Device\\NPF_{8F5BD2E9-253F-4659-8256-B3BCD882AFBC}'
    fp = pcap_open_live(deviceName, 65536, 1, 1000, errbuf)

    if not bool(fp):
        print ("\nUnable to open the adapter.  %s is not supported by WinPcap\n" % deviceName)
        sys.exit(2)

    # FrMessage is a custom class that creates the packet
    test = FrMessage('00:1b:ac:00:47:64', '00:14:d1:2b:1f:19', 0x12345678, 0x4321, 0x55555555, list(i/10 for i in range(320)))

    # test.get_Raw_Packet() returns a c_bytes array needed for winpcap to send the packet
    if (pcap_sendpacket(fp, test.get_Raw_Packet(), test.packet_size) != 0):
        print ("\nError sending the packet: %s\n" % pcap_geterr(fp))
        sys.exit(3)


    elapsed = time.time() - now
    if elapsed < 0.02 and elapsed > 0:
        time.sleep(0.02 - elapsed)

    pcap_close(fp)
```

*Note: I would like to get an array of hex values representing each byte*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What encoding is this, and how do I decode the packet?

What you see is the representation of `bytes` object in Python. As you might have guessed `\xab` represents byte `0xab` (`171`).

> which has weird non hex characters like `!UUUU` or `=`

Printable ASCII characters represent themselves i.e., instead of `\x55` the representation contains just `U`.

What you have is a sequence of bytes. How to decode them depends on your application. For example, to decode a data packet that contains Ethernet frame, you could use [`scapy`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#interactive-tutorial) (Python 2):

```
>>> b = '\x00\x02\x157\xa2D\x00\xae\xf3R\xaa\xd1\x08\x00E\x00\x00C\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x06x<\xc0\xa8\x05\x15B#\xfa\x97\x00\x14\x00P\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x02 \x00\xbb9\x00\x00GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 \n\n'
>>> c = Ether(b)
>>> c.hide_defaults()
>>> c
<Ether  dst=00:02:15:37:a2:44 src=00:ae:f3:52:aa:d1 type=0x800 |
<IP  ihl=5L len=67 frag=0 proto=tcp chksum=0x783c src=192.168.5.21 dst=66.35.250.151 |
<TCP  dataofs=5L chksum=0xbb39 options=[] |
<Raw  load='GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 \n\n' |>>>>
```

> I would like to get an array of hex values representing each byte

You could use [`binascii.hexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex):

```
>>> pkt = b'\x00\x1b\xac\x00Gd\x00'
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(pkt)
b'001bac00476400'
```

or If you want a list with string hex values:

```
>>> hexvalue = binascii.hexlify(pkt).decode()
>>> [hexvalue[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hexvalue), 2)]
['00', '1b', 'ac', '00', '47', '64', '00']
```

Comment: Ultimately what I want is just a hex dump of the raw packet that I'm generating (see update answer).  I would prefer to do this is stock python libs if possible.

Comment: @KronoS: I've updated the answer to show how to get hex values

Answer (score 2):

In python raw packet decode can be done using the `scapy` functions like `IP()`, `TCP()`, `UDP()` etc.

```
import sys
import socket
from scapy.all import *
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
while 1:
    packet = s.recvfrom(2000);
    packet = packet[0]
    ip = IP(packet)
    ip.show()
```